# Laravel 5.3 Redefine "reset email" blade template

Tags: laravel-5.3

How to customize the path of the reset email blade template in Laravel 5.3?

The template used is: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php`

I'd like to build my own.

Also, how to change the text of this email predefined in: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php`

```
public function toMail()
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line([
            'You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.',
            'Click the button below to reset your password:',
        ])
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To change template you should use artisan command `php artisan vendor:publish` it will create blade templates in your `resources/views/vendor` directory. To change text of email you should override the sendPasswordResetNotification method on your User model. This is described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords in **Reset Email Customization** section.

You must add new method to your User model.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

and use your own class for notification instead ResetPasswordNotification.

**UPDATED**: for @lewis4u request

Step by step instruction:

1. To create a new Notification class, you must use this command line `php artisan make:notification MyResetPassword` . It will make a new Notification Class 'MyResetPassword' at app/Notifications directory.
2. add `use App\Notifications\MyResetPassword;` to your User model
3. add new method to your User model.

   ```
   public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
   {
       $this->notify(new MyResetPassword($token));
   }
   ```
4. run php artisan command `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications` After running this command, the mail notification templates will be located in the resources/views/vendor/notifications directory.
5. Edit your `MyResetPassword` class method `toMail()` if you want to. It's described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications
6. Edit your email blade template if you want to. It's `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`

**Bonus:** Laracast video: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/9

PS: Thanks  @Garric15 for suggestion about `php artisan make:notification`

Comment: Also, to create a new Notification class, you must use this command line `php artisan make:notification MyOwnResetPassword` [More here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-override-message-in-sendresetlinkemail-in-forgotpasswordcontroller#reply-183598)

Answer (score 14):

I wanted to elaborate on a very helpful [Eugen’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39610301/3685836), but didn’t have enough reputation to leave a comment.

In case you like to have your own directory structure, you don’t have to use Blade templates published to `views/vendor/notifications/..`. When you create a new Notification class and start building your `MailMessage` class, it has a `view()` method that you can use to override default views:

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->view('emails.password_reset');
        // resources/views/emails/password_reset.blade.php will be used instead.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the above answer for Laravel 5.6, here it is easier to pass variables in an array to your custom email template.

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
$url = url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id);

return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Invoice Paid')
            ->markdown('emails.password_reset', ['url' => $url]);
```

}

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications